# Scale label problem of multiple ListLogPlot graphs

Tags: plotting, graphics

Consider the following code:

```
data1 = {{0.70, 0.05}, {0.71, 0.06}, {0.72, 0.07}};
data2 = {{0.72, 0.07}, {0.72, 0.08}, {0.72, 0.1}, {0.72, 0.2}, {0.72,0.4}, {0.73, 0.6},{0.73, 0.8}, {0.73, 1.0}, {0.73, 2.0}, {0.74, 4.0}, {0.74, 5.0}, {0.74, 6.0}, {0.75, 8.0},{0.78, 10.0}};
data3 = {{0.72, 0.07}, {0.74, 0.08}, {0.76, 0.1}, {0.84, 0.2}, {0.9, 0.4}, {0.96, 0.6}, {1.0, 0.8}, {1.02, 1.0}, {1.12, 2.0}, {1.22, 4.0}, {1.26, 5.0}};

sg = ListLogPlot[Tooltip[data1], Joined -> True, Mesh -> Automatic];
sl = ListLogPlot[Tooltip[data2], Joined -> True, Mesh -> Automatic];
lg = ListLogPlot[Tooltip[data3], Joined -> True, Mesh -> Automatic];
Show[sg, sl, lg, PlotRange -> All]
```

There is no problem with the individual plots but their scales mess up when I combine them using Show command.The scale label just simply disappear. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Try: `Show[sl, sg, lg, PlotRange -> All]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Docs>>Show>>Possible Issues](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html)

> *Show* uses the options from the first graphic

In this case, the `Ticks` and/or `FrameTicks` options from the first graphic are used unless `Show` is provided explicit settings for this option. Since the `PlotRange` and `FrameTicks` settings for `sg` cover only a portion of the whole range for `sl` and `lg`, you see only the ticks/labels from `sg` when you use

```
  Show[sg, sl, lg, PlotRange -> All]
```

First, few changes in the code to distinguish the three plots when they are `Show'n together:

```
sg = ListLogPlot[Tooltip[data1], Joined -> True, Mesh -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Thin, Red]];
sl = ListLogPlot[Tooltip[data2], Joined -> True, Mesh -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Thickness[.01], Blue]];
lg = ListLogPlot[Tooltip[data3], Joined -> True, Mesh -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Thickness[.02], Green]];
```

Since the `PlotRange` and `FrameTicks` settings for `sl` are "more representative" (so to speak), changing the order of graphics in `Show`

```
Show[sl, sg, lg, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

gives

[image]

Alternatively, you could have the input graphics in any order but provide the settings for `FrameTicks` explicitly in `Show` to get the same result:

```
 Show[sg, sl, lg, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  FrameTicks -> (FrameTicks /. sl[[2]])]
```

where I used the facts that

1. You can get the options (not *all* of them, btw) of a graphics object by looking into its second `Part`, that is `sl[[2]]` contains the option settings `PlotRange`, `AxesLabel`, `FrameTicks` ... etc for `sl`.
2. Using the replacement rule `FrameTicks /. sl[[2]]` we get the values of this option in `sl`.